# In backbone, do you define a model's attributes before instantiating?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning backbone.js. In [various](http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/01/backbone-js-part-1/) [tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/) they define particular backbone models by extending `Backbone.Model`

For instance:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});
```

I am a little confused about a basic point: in backbone, do you define the attributes of the model ahead of time? For instance, can you define a person model that can only have two fields: name and age?

Based on my experience creating Java or C# classes, I would expect that you would define the attributes associated with a model in much the same way that you define the fields associated with an object. But this does not seem to be how `backbone.js` works. It seems like you define the attributes associated with a model by setting those attributes during instantiation. For instance, you create age and name fields in a person model by instantiating an instance and setting those fields.  `var person = new Person({ name: "Thomas", age: 67});` Correct?

Relatedly, can you ever do this with a javascript object? I know javascript is interpreted and not compiled so there is no compile-time checking of what fields in a class are getting set/accessed -- but I would think a run-time check would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would only define attributes as part of the model's definition if you needed some default values set:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "species": "homo sapiens"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});
```

Beyond that, the attributes will simply be the properties of whatever object you put into the model. So here's an example:

```
var examplePerson =  new Person({ firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "Smith", age: 30 });
```

Now firstName, lastName, age, and species are the attributes of your model instance. If you want to do validation on the values being set, provide an implementation for Backbone's [validate](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) method.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone encourages the use of its setter and getter functions *.set* and *.get*.  There are some benefits to doing it in this way, every time the setter is used if an attribute changes [an event is fired on the model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).  In this way views (or other models or whatever) can listen to a model and react to attributes changing.

```
   var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({});

   var myCar = new Car({tires:0});

   myCar.listenTo(myCar, 'change:tires', function(){
       console.log('Now with '+myCar.get('tires'));
   }, this);

   myCar.set({tires: 4}); //logs "Now with 4"
```

To access those attributes directly (not recommended) you can access the model's **attributes** object.  You can, of course, still set your own attributes outside of this method by just using *model.myAttribute = myValue* or some such thing but this does NOT fire an event.

```
  myCar.tires = 3;
  myCar.get('tires'); // still 4
```

Backbone attributes are instantiated at several distinct times.  The primary method is the *.set* method, which takes a JSON object, iterates over the keys and saves the values.  This function is used on instantiation of a new model, on syncing/fetching with a server, and when you manually call it.  To fiddle with the instantiation values just add code to the *initialize* method, to fiddle with server responses add code to a model's *parse* method.

If you want to set default values for certain properties you can do so by defining a *defaults* object to your model.  Anyhow, I've enjoyed not having to set the attributes manually so that if I want to adjust my API the changes will pass through nicely.  If you want to not allow certain properties you can always delete them from **attributes** in the *initialize* method.